# Can I submit from a second form and retain POST data from the first?

Tags: php, post

Hopefully I'm making this more difficault then it has to be.  Here is what I'm trying to do. I have a form that does a POST and returns data. I have a second form that then asks the user a yes/no question based on data from the first form.  Is it possible to capture the POST data from the first form submission and pass it along with the second form POST?

Here is my scenario

```
if ($_POST['button_1']) {
    $params = $_POST;
    print_r($_POST);

    // process form data
}
if ($_POST['button_2']) {
    // Retain the POST data from the first submission
    $new_params = $params . $_POST;
    print_r($new_params);

    // process form data and do some additional stuff
}

<form id="form_1" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" value="Button" name="button_1" id="button_1"/>
</form>

<form id="form_2" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" value="Button" name="button_2" id="button_2"/>
</form>
```

Is there a way to do this easily or am I over complicating this?

Comment: Why not save the first POST to a session variable?

Comment: Why do I always forget about SESSION variables?  That'll work, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to "fake" this.

1. Have the first form submit to itself and just load the $_REQUEST variables and use them to populate the second form with the appropriate data/options.
2. have the 2nd form loaded via ajax once the first is submitted and use javascript to grab the current form variables and provide them to the ajax function.

Which method would you prefer?

**UPDATE:
This is long, but a working example**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="first" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="firstformdone">
            <div style="width:100px;float:left;">
                Age:
            </div>
            <div style="width:200px;float:left;margin-left:20px;">
             <input type="text" name="age">
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <div style="width:100px;float:left;">
                Name:
            </div>
            <div style="width:200px;float:left;margin-left:20px;">
             <input type="text" name="name">
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <br>
            <?PHP
                if (!$_REQUEST['action'] == "firstformdone") {
            ?>
            <input type="submit" value="contine">
            <?PHP
                }
            ?>
        </form>
        <?PHP
            if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "firstformdone") {
        ?>
        <form name="second" action="something_else.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="age" value="<?PHP echo $_REQUEST['age']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?PHP echo $_REQUEST['name']; ?>">
            <div style="width:150px;float:left;">
                Preferred games:
            </div>
            <div style="width:200px;float:left;margin-left:20px;">
                <select name="games">
                    <option value="">Select games</option>
                    <?PHP
                        if ($_REQUEST['age'] <= 10) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="tlddlywinks">Tiddly Winks</option>
                    <option value="Jacks">Jacks</option>
                    <option value="Go-Fish">Go-Fish</option>
                    <option value="Hid-And-Go-Seek">Hid-And-Go-Seek</option>
                    <?PHP
                        } else {
                    ?>
                    <option value="Halo">Halo</option>
                    <option value="StarWars">The Old Republic</option>
                    <option value="LaserTag">Laser Tag</option>
                    <option value="spin-the-bottle">spin-the-bottle</option>
                    <?PHP
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Next!">
        </form>
        <?PHP
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to stay away from ajax for now so maybe I'll try the first method.

Comment: in that case you can just have the 2nd form not be present until you submit the first. perhaps if($_REQUEST) { build 2nd form ) or smiliar

Comment: and yes, if you have lots of form elements, use the post from @mario to build all the hidden fields :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to package the data from the first form up for resubmission. You can use a hidden fields for that job:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    print "<input type='hidden' name='".htmlspecialchars($key, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")."' value='".htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8")."'>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a hidden field in your second form, or sessions. Start reading here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the standard way is to use **type = "hidden"** fields to pass this context data onto the second form.  There are lots of worked examples to see how to do this.  View the source of this HTML page or any other with forms on them and search for "hidden" to see how the applications do this.